# Rails4 about helper_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have question about `helper_method`.

When I add fuc in `/controller/application_controller.rb`

```
helper_method :values

def values
  @food = Food.all
  @food_type = FoodType.all
end
```

I want to use var on `/layouts/application.html.erb`

code here

```
<% @food.each do |fp|%>
  <p><%= fp.name %></p>
<% end %>

<% @food_type.each do |ft|%>
  <p><%= ft.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

but it return nill .

Please teach me ,thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

application_controller.rb

```
def values
  @food = Food.all
  @food_type = FoodType.all
  [@food, @food_type]
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<%food, food_type = values%>
<% food.each do |fp|%>
<p><%= fp.name %></p>
<% end %>

<% food_type.each do |ft|%>
<p><%= ft.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thx a lot ,but I want to know why must be set val?

Have any idea can autoload helper don't use `<%food, food_type = 
values%>`

Answer (score 0):

**DRY**

You'll be much better using the [`before_action`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) callback

The problem you have is a `helper` is meant as a simple way to create functionality for your application. IE that you pass some data *to* the helper, it will "crunch" the data, and return a reasonable response.

This is why `Vimsha`'s answer has been accepted - he has made it so that your *helper method* will return the values you need; consequently meaning you need to call the method if you want to use the data it has .

--

The **real** answer for you (considering you just want to be able to use the `@food` and `@food_type` variables in your application layout), is to use a callback which sets these variables each time:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :set_vars

   private

   def set_vars
      @food = Food.all
      @food_type = FoodType.all
   end
end
```

Although relatively inefficient (you'll be best caching this data so it won't be pinging your DB each time), you'll be able to use `@food` and `@food_type` in your application layout with no issues